# Twilio returns 502 while pointing to AWS API Gateway hooked to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a twilio number pointing to an AWS API Gateway which is hooked to an AWS lambda function which returns XML. After multiple attempts I was finally able to to map the response from Lambda to API gateway and now it is returning valid XML for twilio. If I try to go to the URL or I try to make a curl to the URL I get the expected result: some XML. However, when I try this from twilio I get 502 Bad gateway. Nay ideas why? Also I tried this from multiple IP address so I don't think it is a security issue, since I don't have any security enabled or authentication on the API gateway. I need help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this thanks to the help from this post [Twilio - TwiML with SNI Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834358/twilio-twiml-with-sni-support)

Basically it was a SNI problem. Apparently Twilio doesn't yet support SNI.